# Сумма нескольких слагаемых в модульной арифметике

Tags: математика, mod

Насколько мне известно,

```
(a+b) mod q = (a mod q + b mod q) mod q
```

Но что делать, если речь идет о сумме более, чем двух слагаемых?

```
(a+b+c) mod q = ((a+b)+c) mod q = ((a+b) mod q + c mod q) mod q = ((a mod q + b mod q) mod q + c mod q) mod q
```

Но вместе с тем я встречал утверждения, что

```
(a+b+c) mod q = (a mod q + b mod q + c mod q) mod q
```

(хотя `(a+b)mod q` не равно `a mod q + b mod q)`.

Какой же из вариантов (или оба?) является правильным?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Любой из приведенных вариантов - лишь бы *в процессе сложения* **не** *возникло переполнения*. Математически они эквивалентны.

Просто представьте

```
a = kq + x,  0 <= x < q
b = lq + y,  0 <= y < q
c = mq + z,  0 <= z < q
```

распишите все эти формулы и убедитесь, что все работает.

Ну, например,

```
(a+b+c)mod q = ((k+l+m)q + x+y+z) mod q = (x+y+z) mod q
```

С другой стороны,

```
(a mod q + b mod q + c mod q) mod q = (x+y+z) mod q
```